# Bootstrap Datepicker Format Could Not Change To dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi I have the following code and i am trying to change DatePicker as documentation but it did notchange. Please take a look at my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        $('#lmp').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        }).on('changeDate',  function (ev) {
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        }); 
    })
</script>
```

And This is my HTML Code

```
<input class="span2" type="text" name="lmp" id="lmp" placeholder="Click To  Choose Date"  align="left">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `dateFormat` to `format`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
    $('#lmp').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    }).on('changeDate',  function (ev) {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    }); 
})
```